# Difference between much, high and great

Tags: word-usage

- Much weight (not high weight or great weight)
- Great thickness (not high thickness or much thickness)
- High temperature (not much temperature or great temperature)

Is there differences between much, high and great?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is idiom.  But you aren't quite right.

"High temperature" is right, as is "great thickness"

You can say "a high weight", or "great weight" but normally you'd just say "heavy".  "Much weight" is not particularly idiomatic

> He felt as if a great weight had been lifted from his shoulders.

> He had given up the diet and his weight was as high as it ever was.

No rule, just idiom.  This kind of idiom is called collocation.  Some words tend to go together.